# On Windows, how can I tell when a USB device goes to sleep from "USB Selective Suspend"

Tags: c#, windows, usb, wndproc

I have a C# application interfacing to a USB barcode scanner. Everything works fine until Windows suspends the USB bus.  Turning off "USB Selective Suspend" in the power settings is not an option. I need to detect when the device (or the usb bus) gets suspended.

I can detect when a USB device is connected or disconnected by overriding WndProc in a NativeWindow instance.

```
protected override void WndProc(ref Message m)
    {
        switch (m.Msg)
        {
            case WM_DEVICECHANGE:    // (0x0219)

                Console.WriteLine("Device presence Changed");
                
                switch (m.WParam.ToInt32()) 
                {
                    case Win32Usb.DEVICE_ARRIVAL:   // inserted (0x8000)
                        Console.WriteLine("Device Inserted");
                        break;
                    case Win32Usb.DEVICE_REMOVECOMPLETE:    // removed (0x8004)
                        Console.WriteLine("Device Removed");
                        break;
                }                    
                break;                
        }

        base.WndProc(ref m);
    }
```

But it does not tell me when a USB device gets suspended by Windows.

Anyone know the m.Msg or m.WParam that can tell me when a USB device goes to sleep (or wakes up)?

I know there are lots of USB libraries on nuget and most of them can tell you when a device is inserted/removed, but I can't find any to detect "USB Selective Suspend". I'm open to using 3rd party library if you know of one that can solve my problem.